# J2me+images in form

Tags: java-me

I want to make the clock application where user enters the number in the textbox and click ok then user get the number at every 1 sec.
Example if user enter 5 then the timer start the display screen shows the number 1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,...so on.

Now i had taken form and text field for user to enter the number,then a timer which will change the number at every second.and 10 images of number (0-9).As i want to dispaly the number in very large size.Now i had implement this logic in below way:-

> public class Clock extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {
>
> ```
> public Command GO, Exit;
> TextField TxtData;
> protected Display display;
> int number, counter;
> Form form;
> private Timer timer;
> private TestTimerTask task;
> boolean increment, time;
> private StringItem s1 = new StringItem("", "");
> Image image0;
> Image image1;
> Image image2;
> Image image3;
> Image image4;
> Image image5;
> Image image6;
> Image image7;
> Image image8;
> Image image9;
> Image[] secondAnimation;
> protected void startApp() {
>     display = Display.getDisplay(this);
>     increment = true;
>     time = false;
>     form = new Form("Clock");
>     TxtData = new TextField("Number:-", "", 5, TextField.NUMERIC);
>     try {
>         image0 = Image.createImage("/images/0.png");
>         image1 = Image.createImage("/images/1.png");
>         image2 = Image.createImage("/images/2.png");
>         image3 = Image.createImage("/images/3.png");
>         image4 = Image.createImage("/images/4.png");
>         image5 = Image.createImage("/images/5.png");
>         image6 = Image.createImage("/images/6.png");
>         image7 = Image.createImage("/images/7.png");
>         image8 = Image.createImage("/images/8.png");
>         image9 = Image.createImage("/images/9.png");
>            secondAnimation = new Image[]{image0,image1,image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9};
>
>     } catch (IOException ex) {
>       System.out.println("exception");
>     }
>     GO = new Command("Go", Command.OK, 1);
>     Exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 2);
>     form.append(TxtData);
>     form.append(s1);
>
>     form.addCommand(GO);
>     form.addCommand(Exit);
>     form.setCommandListener(this);
>     display.setCurrent(form);
> }
>
> protected void pauseApp() {
> }
>
> protected void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
>     timer.cancel();
>     notifyDestroyed();
> }
>
> public void commandAction(Command cmnd, Displayable dsplbl) {
>     String label = cmnd.getLabel();
>     if (label.equals("Go")) {
>         try {
>             System.out.println("txt==" + (TxtData.getString()));
>             if (!TxtData.getString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
>                 counter = Integer.parseInt(TxtData.getString());
>                 if (time) {
>                     timer.cancel();
>                     task.cancel();
>                 }
>                 number = 1;
>                 timer = new Timer();
>                 task = new TestTimerTask();
>                 timer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000);
>
>             }
>         } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
>             System.out.println("exception");
>         }
>
>     } else if (label.equals("Exit")) {
>         destroyApp(true);
>     }
>
> }
>
> private class TestTimerTask extends TimerTask {
>
>     public final void run() {
>         time = true;
>
>         s1.setText(""+ number);
>          if (counter < 10) {
>             form.append(secondAnimation[0]);
>             form.append(secondAnimation[0]);
>             form.append(secondAnimation[number]);
>         } else if (counter < 100) {
>              form.append(secondAnimation[0]);
>             form.append(secondAnimation[(number % 100) / 10]);
>             form.append(secondAnimation[(number % 10)]);
>         } else if (counter < 1000) {
>             form.append(secondAnimation[(number % 10)]);
>             form.append(secondAnimation[(number % 100) / 10]);
>             form.append(secondAnimation[(number / 100)]);
>         }
>         number++;
>         if (number == counter + 1) {
>             number = 0;
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

But as the form goes on appending the image as timer moves it is not showing the desired output!

I had tried to do it through LWUIT but as i had user 10 .png files and adding LWUIT.jar file make the size of .jar file 557kb which is very heavy.

So i want to do it through normal forms only.

I cant use canvas as the keypad can vary like (touch,qwerty etc).So i need to do normal form or LWUIT only.Can anyone please help me for this.

Comment: Did you use obfuscating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you only `append` items but never remove - is that intended?

Also, did you try two different forms to animate instead of one? For simple test, say, fill them in parallel, just call `setCurrent` for one that is not displayed in the moment of update

```
//...
private void appendTwice(Image image) {
    form1.append(image);
    form2.append(image);
}
//...
public final void run() {
    time = true;

    s1.setText(""+ number);
     if (counter < 10) {
        appendTwice(secondAnimation[0]);
        //...
    }
    display.setCurrent(number & 1 == 0 ? form1 : form2);
    number++;
    //...
}
//...
```